Graceful Shutdown for Spring boot with TaskExecutor - ExecutorService in shutdown state did not accept task
I'm experiencing an issue with handling asynchronous tasks during a graceful shutdown in my Spring Boot application, deployed on Kubernetes. Here’s the scenario:
I have configured graceful shutdown to stop receiving new HTTP requests and allow 60 seconds for ongoing requests to complete.
When an HTTP request comes in and is processed by an @Async method, if the shutdown signal is received after the request is accepted but before it's passed to the async method, I encounter the following error:
ExecutorService in shutdown state did not accept task:
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor

my config is:
    private Executor getExecutor(ThreadPoolProperties threadPoolProperties) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolProperties.getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolProperties.getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(threadPoolProperties.getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(threadPoolProperties.getQueueCapacity());
    
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);

        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

application.yml
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      shutdown:
        await-termination: true
        await-termination-period: 60s
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 60s
  
server:
  shutdown: graceful

Spring boot 3.3.3 and java21 is my setup
This indicates that the ExecutorService is in a shutdown state and not accepting new tasks. How can I handle this scenario to ensure that the async task is still accepted and executed, even if the shutdown signal is received just before the task is passed to the async method?
I'm looking for suggestions or best practices on resolving this.
